# React map unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, for-loop

I've got this function in my `Global.jsx` file:

```
FeGruHasChilds: (childs) => {
    childs.map((c, i) => {
        if (c.VALUEDB != null && c.VALUEDB != "") {
            console.log(c.VALUEDB);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

I'm calling it like this:

```
Global.FeGruHasChilds(myArray) &&
myArray.map((c, i) =>{
<MyComponent value=myArray[i].VALUEDB/>
})
```

My expected behaviour is, that if any item in `myArray` has an `VALUEDB` then `FeGruHasChilds` should return `true` and quit the function and react should render `MyComponent` for every item in `myArray`.

Actual behaviour: The function doesn't quit if there is an item with `VALUEDB`, it does check it for all items (I logged it in the console). And also there is never any `MyComponent` rendered. It's always empty.

EDIT: 
tried to execute it like this:

`<button onClick={() => console.log(Global.FeGruHasChilds(myArray))}>TEST</button>`

It returns `undefined`

Comment: Add a filter method to put a condition whether valuedb is available or not

Comment: How is your myArray and childs looks like?

Comment: Every item in the array has a `VALUE` and a `VALUEDB` and in this test-case every item has `VALUEDB` filled with "100".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to return `true` if any of the items passes a test, you can use [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
FeGruHasChilds: (childs) =>
    childs.some(c => c.VALUEDB !== null && c.VALUEDB !== ""); // c => c would be enough if you have strings or null
```

In your case `Array.map()` returns an array of `true` and `false`. An array by itself is a truthy value, and should have caused the components to be rendered all them time. However, you don't return the result from the function, and the function always returns `undefined`. Undefined is a falsy value, so the components never render. You can return the value by using the `return` key word, or just remove the curly brackets of the arrow function:

```
FeGruHasChilds: (childs) => {
    childs.map((c, i) => { // not returned 
        if (c.VALUEDB != null && c.VALUEDB != "") {
            console.log(c.VALUEDB);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now it works, but why doesn't `return true` just return `true` as the result of the function?

Comment: @DanielRose - in any case return only terminate its current function scope, and not it's parents. When you use map, the callbacks are invoked, inside the map, and the return value is collected, and returned by the map. Because it happens in a function, you should've returned the value.

Comment: check if `FeGruHasChilds: (childs) =>
    childs.some((c) => !!c.VALUEDB );` wouldn't be enought

Comment: hmmm, it's exactly opposite - `const arr=['',null,0,undefined,'s']; console.log( arr.some((c) => !!c ));` returns true and false if I remove `'s'`- as expected?

Comment: But the original code would have return `true` for the `0` and the `undefined` as well.

Comment: For `0` I agree but `undefined` is hard to name 'having value'  `arr.some((c) => !!c || c===0 )` is still shorter ;) If you need boolean `false` : `arr.some((c) => !!c || c===0 || c===false )` - for sure it depends on exact requirements